# Condition with state doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several buttons with different values, and i need user to click them all, only then access will be provided. So it turns out that i'm using weird if statement cuz it doesn't work. This is my code:

```js
export const SubscribeOnOthers: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [subscribed, setSubscribed] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const users = [
    { nickname: "@user1" },
    { nickname: "@user2" },
    { nickname: "@user3" },
    { nickname: "@user4" },
  ];

  const checkAllSubs = useCallback(() => {
    users.map(({ nickname }) => {
      if (!subscribed.includes(nickname)) {
        setIsError((prev) => true);
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isError) {
        console.log("all is good")
      }
    },1000)
  }, [isError])
  return (
    ...
  )
```

So i have 4 members and user have to subscribe on each member(let's think if he clicked, he subscribed)
When the user click on any button, value of that button is writing to `subscribed` state.
And when the user click on button named `check all subscriptions` that function `checkAllSubs` is called.
But when i have not all users in `subscribed` state, router consoles "all is good" anyway in 1 sec
Where is the problem

Comment: You should define the method `checkAllSubs` as React.useCallBack with `isError` as  a dependency of it.

Comment: @user1672994 didn't help( I updated code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rethink a bit this component, I don't see why to use setTimeout but anyway, useState is not synchronous so it is still false in the if statement. Instead, use a variable as flag, not a state.
And in this case also best practice to use a forEach instead of a map, because you are not returning any array.

```
const checkAllSubs = ()=>{
let isError=false
    users.forEach(({ nickname }) => {
      if (!subscribed.includes(nickname)) {
        IsError=true;
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isError) {
        console.log("all is good")
      }
    },1000)
  }
  return (
    ...
  )
```

And if you are using useCallback remember to add subscribed to your dependency array